# cordova plugin splash screen not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-splashscreen to displaying the splash screen.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

It was working previously, but it is not working for new builds. Here is my config file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <widget id="in.fifa" version="1.0" versionCode="005" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   <name>FIFA18</name>
   <description>
       Sample Description
   </description>
   <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
       Author Name
    </author>
   <content src="index.html" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"/>
   <platform name="android">
      <splash src="screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
      <splash src="screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
      <splash src="screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
      <splash src="screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
   </platform>
   <icon src="icon.png" /> 

   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1500"/>
   <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
   <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
   <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="40000"/>
   <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true"/>

   <access origin="*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />  
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
   <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
   <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
   <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
   <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15"/>
      <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
      <preference name="multiDexEnabled" value="true"/>
   </platform>
   <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
   </platform>
```

Splash screen image is available in the project root folder. Is there any code needs to be changed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "screen.png" resides in your cordova project folder. If you have moved the file to something like `YOUR_CORDOVA_PROJECT/res/img/screen/screen.png` then you need to respect that path in your config.xml, like so:

```
<splash src="res/img/screen/screen.png" density="port-hdpi" />
```

If that didn't resolve the issue, make sure that your config.xml structure matches the one in this example:

```
<?xml version= ... ?>
<widget id= ...>
    ...
    <platform name="android">
        <splash src="path/to/screen.png" density="port-ldpi" />
        <splash src="path/to/screen.png" density="port-mdpi" />
        ...
    </platform>
    ...
</widget>
```

Also make sure that you are not testing the splash screen on your device in landscape mode, as you have only added configuration for the portrait mode in the provided code snippet.

Comment: I have edited my initial answer to reflect the config.xml structure more clearly. If that didn't help, is it possible for you to post the contents of your config.xml here? Also, are you absolutely sure that you have stored the splash screen images in the project root folder? This would be very atypical and you should consider moving them to the provided res/ folder instead.

Comment: I think you need to put all `<splash>` tags containing a `density` attribute inside the `<platform name="android"> ... </platform>` tags. The `density` attribute is only supported for the android platform.

See this example in the docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#example-configuration